# Filter multidimensional array by keywords in (ex: title or description) values (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter, preg-grep

How to filter multidimensional array with specific keyword in 'title' OR 'description' values, like the data array below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 873
            [title] => Mark
            [description] => John Doe Billy
            [category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 52
                    [name] => Wall Art
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 266
            [title] => Ninja Turle
            [description] => Mark Doe
            [category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 52
                    [name] => Wall Art
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 227
            [title] => Red Rose 
            [description] => Billy Jean
            [category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 52
                    [name] => Wall Art
                )
        )

)
```

previously i used below code, and it worked and display according to what I needed, but at the same time i got error msg "Notice: Array to string conversion".

```
$search = "/mark/i";

$products = array_filter($data, function($a) use($search)  {
    return preg_grep($search, $a);
});
```

Am I missing something with the code? or is there a better way.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this notice because key `category` is **array**. PHP tries to convert this array to string so as to apply `preg_grep`, that's why you receive this warning. I suppose you can do something like:

```
$search = "mark";

$products = array_filter($data, function($a) use($search)  {
    return false !== stripos($a['title'], $search) 
        || false !== stripos($a['description'], $search);
});
```

**Updated** variant - unset array value and run `preg_grep` on the rest of values, which are strings:

```
$search = "/mark/i";

$products = array_filter($data, function($a) use($search)  {
    unset($a['category']);
    return preg_grep($search, $a);
});
```

Comment: it worked, thank you. Do you think this is the proper way? or there's a better way?

Comment: My answer helps to avoid the warning. I don't see better way, `preg_grep` is nice when all elements of array are strings. Also you can `unset` `category` key and still use `preg_grep`, maybe it's a better solution - updated answer, but if in `$a` there will be more subarrays, you'll have to `unset` them too. Also, as a hack - `@` operator can be used which supress warnings, but it's the last solution that I will use.